# Form validation without error on IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html code saved as a php, the form validation works in google chrome but not in IE. In IE after I hit the submit button, the page automatically goes to process form regardless of errors.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Week 8 Lab - JavaScript DOM and Arrays</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
  <script>
    function validateForm() {
        var errors = 0;
        var fName = document.forms["orderForm"].firstName.value;//first name validation
        if (fName == null || fName == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML = "Please enter a first name.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('firstNameError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        //var lName = document.forms["orderForm"].lastName.value;//last name validation
        if (lName == null || lName == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML = "Please enter a last name.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('lastNameError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        //var address = document.forms["orderForm"].address.value;//address validation
        if (address == null || address == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML = "Please enter an address.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('addressError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        //var city = document.forms["orderForm"].city.value;//city validation
        if (city == null || city == "")
        {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML = "Please enter a city.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('cityError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        //var pCodeCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;//postal code validation
        if (pCodeCheck)
        {
            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML = "";
        }
        else
        {

            document.getElementById('postalCoderror').innerHTML = "Please enter a valid postal code.";
            errors++;
        }

        // makes sure you cannot order a negative number of items


        var itemQTY = document.forms["orderForm"].widget1qty.value;
        if (itemQTY < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML = "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('qtyError').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var itemQTY2 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget2qty.value;
        if (itemQTY2 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML = "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('qtyError2').innerHTML = "";
        }


        var itemQTY3 = document.forms["orderForm"].widget3qty.value;
        if (itemQTY3 < 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML = "You cannot enter a negative number.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('qtyError3').innerHTML = "";
        }

        //makes sure there is at least one item ordered
        var wid1Qty = document.getElementById('widget1qty').value;
        var wid2Qty = document.getElementById('widget2qty').value;
        var wid3Qty = document.getElementById('widget3qty').value;
        if (wid1Qty + wid2Qty + wid3Qty == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML = "You must order atleast one item.";
            errors++;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('itemQTY').innerHTML = "";
        }
        var total1;
        var total2;
        var total3;
        var total4;

        total1 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget1qty'].value * 5;
        total2 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget2qty'].value * 15;
        total3 = document.forms['orderForm']['widget3qty'].value * 25;
        total4 = (total1 + total2 + total3);
        alert('Your total is: $' + total4 + '.00');
        return errors;
    }

    function startValidate() {
        var errors = validateForm();
        if (errors == 0) {
            document.forms['orderForm'].submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h2 class="center">Order Form</h2> <!-- action="processForm.html"       "javascript:void(0)" -->
            <form name="orderForm" method="post" action="processForm.html" onsubmit="return startValidate()">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="required">*</span>First Name:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" size="30"></td>
                            <td id="firstNameError"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="required">*</span>Last Name:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" size="30"></td>
                            <td id="lastNameError"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="required">*</span>Address:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30"></td>
                            <td id="addressError"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="required">*</span>City:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30"></td>
                            <td id="cityError"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="required">*</span>Province:</td>
                            <td><select name="province" id="province" size="1">
                                    <option disabled>Select a province</option>
                                    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
                                    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
                                    <option value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
                                    <option value="MB">Manitoba</option>
                                    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                                    <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                                    <option value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
                                    <option value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
                                    <option value="PE">Prince Edward Island</option>
                                    <option value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
                                    <option value="YK">Yukon</option>
                                    <option value="NWT">Northwest Territories</option>
                                    <option value="NU">Nunavut</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span class="required">*</span>Postal Code:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="postalCode" id="postalCode" maxlength="6"></td>
                            <td id="postalCoderror"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Order Information</legend>

                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="3"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3">Select your products:<br>
                            <td>Widget #1&nbsp;
                                <input type="text" name="widget1qty" id="widget1qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$5.00/ea</strong></td>
                            <td id="qtyError"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Widget #2&nbsp;
                                <input type="text" name="widget2qty" id="widget2qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$15.00/ea</strong></td>
                            <td id="qtyError2"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Widget #3&nbsp;
                                <input type="text" name="widget3qty" id="widget3qty" size="1" value="0">Qty @ <strong>$25.00/ea</strong></td>
                            <td id="qtyError3"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3"></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td id="itemQTY"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3">Shipping Type:</td>
                            <td>Standard ($5.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeStandard" value="Standard" checked></td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Express ($10.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeExpress" value="Express"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Overnight ($20.00)<input type="radio" name="shippingType" id="shippingTypeOvernight" value="Overnight"></td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Submit Order</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="2"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit Order">
                        <td><input type="reset" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" value="Reset Form"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

Comment: Remove `return` in front of `startValidate()`. You should use external JavaScript and AJAX really, so you can validate both Client and Server side, as the Client can easily be hacked.

Comment: try to use the debugging tools for IE. sometimes chrome lets you get aways from those superfluous commas, but IE does not

Comment: removed return and I'm still have the same problem

Comment: which is the IE version?

Comment: apparently my if (lName == null || lName == "") is undefined, which makes no sense because that would mean my var address should be undefined also    edit: and now there's no error at all but it's still not validating

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the console in IE’s developer tools (F12), you will see that there is an error message about undeclared variable `lName`. This causes the error checking to be aborted.

You have several lines like

```
//var lName = document.forms["orderForm"].lastName.value;//last name validation
```

Since `//` starts a comment in JavaScript, the line has no effect. The variable `lName` is not declared or defined elsewhere either.

So you need to remove those `//` comment starters. Note that the code does not work in Chrome either; you may have tested a different version in Chrome, or misinterpreted some behavior.

In the console, you can also see a message for line 237 about “unexpected identifier”. It is actually a serious HTML markup error; IE reports some of such errors, in a strange way. The error is that a `tr` element has an `input` element as child, which is forbidden in HTML syntax. This is why the Submit Order and Reset Form appear on top of each other and not on the same row as intended. (For usability, the Reset Form button should be removed, but I digress.)